# Upgrade of Nexus 3.15.2 (containing nexus2 proxy repos) to 3.26.1

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm planning to upgrade Nexus 3.15.2 (containing nexus2 proxy repos running in same server as different instance) to 3.26.1

Thinking to follow https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000350007-Upgrading-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3, but this doesn't explicitly say any thing on existing nexus2 proxy repos.

Would like to know upon upgrading from 3.15.2 to 3.26.1 will there be any issues to existing nexus2 proxy repos? or after upgrade of 3.26.1, should I need to once again undergo enabling 'Upgrade capabilities' followed by perform 'upgrade by choosing nexus 2 repos' from Nexus 3.26.1 to restore those proxy connections for accessing those artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

All your proxies should remain intact in the upgrade.
Note, if you have any doubt carefully review the [release notes](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Release+Notes) and try in a testing environment.  We recommend this for big upgrades anyway, such as yours, over 10 versions difference.
And always recommend backup before any upgrade as well in case it goes awry.